# Adding longtables to appendix, latex it takes a lot of time to create the pdf

Tags: longtable, appendix

this is my code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{float,subfig}
    \usepackage{adjustbox,tabularx,ragged2e}
    \usepackage{amsmath,geometry,booktabs}
    \usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn,longtable}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} 
    \usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

    \begin{document}
    \listoffigures % Prints the list of figures
    \listoftables % Prints the list of tables
    \tableofcontents

        %%APPENDIX A    
        \begin{appendices}
    \chapter[]{}
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c c }
            \toprule
            \textbf{Geological fm}& \textbf{number of samples examined}\\
            \hline
            MAC&    34\\
            OMT &34\\
            FAF &18\\
            PSM &16\\
            GRE &13\\
            ARB &8\\
            ACC &7\\
            ACCa&7\\
            GOT &7\\
            PRS &7\\
            CGV &6\\
            MAA &5\\
            CCA &4\\
            MDD &4\\
            STO &4\\
            ANL &3\\
            CLF &3\\
            MRQ &3\\
            RET &3\\
            ACCb &2\\
            bv &2\\
            CCVd& 2\\
            MAS &2\\
            MVE &2\\
            OST &2\\
            PRC &2\\
            SSR &2\\
            VEU &2\\
            CCVb &1\\
            CCVc &1\\
            LVG &1\\
            MACa &1\\
            MRR &1\\
            pv  &1\\
            VINa &1\\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
        \caption{Number of samples for each geological formation examined in the laboratory for the unit weight determination.}
        \label{tab:count_pesovol}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{S[table-format=2.0]
            *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]}
            S[table-format=2.1,detect-weight]
        }
        \caption{Results of linear regression model for the prediction of R mean (R mean predicted).}\\
        \label{tab:model_res_t} \\
        \toprule
        {Mv(\%)} 
        & {L mean }& {R mean observed} & {R mean predicted} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{Results of linear regression model for the prediction of R mean (R mean predicted).} \\           
        \toprule
        {Mv(\%)}
        & {L mean }& {R mean observed} & {R mean predicted} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        85  &   188.2   &   10.0    &   9.3 \\
        80  &   375.3   &   10.5    &   20.4    \\
        75  &   326.2   &   23.4    &   17.5    \\
        40  &   247.1   &   15.6    &   13.1    \\
        30  &   215.1   &   18.2    &   11.3    \\
        25  &   258.9   &   16.0    &   13.9    \\
        20  &   243.8   &   16.9    &   13.1    \\
        20  &   264.0   &   11.8    &   14.3    \\
        10  &   285.4   &   17.6    &   15.6    \\
        10  &   295.7   &   19.3    &   16.2    \\
        5   &   239.9   &   14.7    &   13.0    \\
        5   &   281.3   &   23.3    &   15.4    \\
        0   &   296.9   &   18.4    &   16.4    \\
        0   &   304.8   &   21.1    &   16.9    \\
        0   &   321.9   &   21.6    &   17.9    \\
        0   &   375.6   &   27.1    &   21.0    \\
        0   &   413.0   &   21.1    &   23.2    \\
        0   &   444.9   &   18.4    &   25.1    \\
        0   &   449.1   &   34.3    &   25.4    \\
        0   &   484.7   &   34.3    &   27.5    \\
        0   &   489.3   &   33.9    &   27.7    \\
        0   &   505.8   &   21.1    &   28.7    \\
        0   &   542.1   &   41.9    &   30.9    \\
        0   &   563.9   &   34.3    &   32.1    \\
        0   &   572.4   &   34.3    &   32.6    \\
        0   &   646.2   &   34.3    &   37.0    \\
        0   &   662.2   &   41.9    &   37.9    \\
        0   &   538.8   &   23.1    &   30.7    \\
        0   &   466.3   &   18.2    &   26.4    \\
        0   &   377.9   &   12.7    &   21.2    \\
        0   &   636.7   &   32.6    &   36.4    \\
        0   &   691.2   &   38.4    &   39.7    \\
        0   &   766.8   &   48.6    &   44.1    \\
        0   &   614.5   &   24.3    &   35.1    \\
        0   &   543.7   &   23.0    &   31.0    \\
        0   &   499.8   &   16.5    &   28.4    \\
        0   &   710.3   &   35.1    &   40.8    \\
        0   &   774.0   &   50.5    &   44.6    \\
        0   &   780.0   &   49.1    &   44.9    \\
        0   &   761.3   &   49.5    &   43.8    \\
        0   &   762.9   &   50.1    &   43.9    \\
        0   &   767.0   &   50.3    &   44.1    \\
        0   &   588.1   &   35.0    &   33.6    \\
        0   &   601.7   &   38.7    &   34.4    \\
        0   &   423.9   &   11.3    &   23.9    \\
        0   &   425.3   &   10.5    &   24.0    \\
        0   &   623.7   &   29.9    &   35.7    \\  
\end{longtable}


\begin{longtable}{S[table-format=2.0]
            *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]}
            S[table-format=2.1,detect-weight]
        }
        \caption{Results of Bayesian Network model for the prediction of R mean (R mean predicted).}\\
        \label{tab:model_res_tot_BN} \\
        \toprule
        {Mv(\%)} 
        & {L mean }& {R mean observed} & {R mean predicted} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{Results of Bayesian Network model for the prediction of R mean (R mean predicted).} \\
        \toprule
        {Mv(\%)}
        & {L mean }& {R mean observed} & {R mean predicted} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        85 &188.2   &10.0   &8.6  \\
        80 &375.3   &10.5   &20   \\
        75 &326.2   &23.4   &19.1 \\
        40 &247.1   &15.6   &14.3 \\
        30 &215.1   &18.2   &11.5 \\
        25 &258.9   &16.0   &15.2 \\
        20 &243.8   &16.9   &14.1 \\
        20 &264.0   &11.8   &15.6 \\
        10 &285.4   &17.6   &16.5 \\
        10 &295.7   &19.3   &17.1 \\
        5  &239.9   &14.7   &13.9 \\
        5  &281.3   &23.3   &16.3 \\
        0  &780.0   &49.1   &50.6 \\
        0  &264     &11.8   &15.6 \\
        0  &285.8   &17.6   &16.5 \\
        0  &295.7   &19.3   &17.1 \\
        0  &239.9   &14.7   &13.9 \\
        0  &296.9   &18.4   &17.4 \\
        0  &304.8   &21.1   &18.0 \\
        0  &321.9   &21.6   &19.1 \\
        0  &375.6   &27.1   &20.3 \\
        0  &413.0   &21.1   &21.4 \\
        0  &444.9   &18.4   &22.8 \\
        0  &449.1   &34.3   &23.3 \\
        0  &484.7   &34.3   &25.3 \\
        0  &489.3   &33.9   &25.3 \\
        0  &505.8   &21.1   &26.4 \\
        0  &542.1   &41.9   &28.3 \\
        0  &563.9   &34.3   &29.8 \\
        0  &572.4   &34.3   &30.3 \\
        0  &646.2   &34.3   &35.7 \\
        0  &662.2   &41.9   &36.9 \\
        0  &538.8   &23.1   &28.7 \\
        0  &466.3   &18.2   &24.2 \\
        0  &377.9   &12.7   &20.4 \\
        0  &636.7   &32.6   &35.2 \\
        0  &691.2   &38.4   &38.6 \\
        0  &766.8   &48.6   &43.3 \\
        0  &614.5   &24.3   &33.6 \\
        0  &543.7   &23.0   &29.0 \\
        0  &499.8   &16.5   &25.9 \\
        0  &710.3   &35.1   &38.8 \\
        0  &774.0   &50.5   &48.5 \\
        0  &780.0   &49.1   &50.6 \\
        0  &761.3   &49.5   &41.1 \\
        0  &762.9   &50.1   &41.4 \\
        0  &767.0   &50.3   &43.4 \\
        0  &588.1   &35.0   &31.4 \\
        0  &601.7   &38.7   &32.6 \\
        0  &423.9   &11.3   &21.9 \\
        0  &425.3   &10.5   &22.2 \\
        0  &623.7   &29.9   &33.7 \\
\end{longtable}
    \onehalfspacing
    \end{appendices}

    %\printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE is not compilable. Missed are some packages (`booktabs`, siunitx`, ...). Please check it again and correct all errors in it.

Comment: After adding missing packages, correcting errors in table codes and remove commands for changing spaces ( why you use them?), you MWE compilation time is short as expected.

Comment: I edited the code, anyway latex is still running and it doesn't produce the pdf. The file xxx.synctex is still busy from yesterday. I also have reboot the computer. @Zarko

Comment: You still have error in line 80 of your code. Missed is `\\ ` after `\caption` in `longtable`. Also `\onehalfspacing` and `\singlespacing` are not defined. After remowing them and miising `\\ ` your MWE compile fine and for compilation on my (very) old PC need about 6 seconds ...

Comment: Please, repair your MWE as I suggested in above comment, delete `.aux`, `.log`, `.sync`, `.lof`, .`lot` and `.toc` files of this MWE and than try again to compile it again.

Comment: now is working, question is edited with corrections.  thank you @Zarko!

Comment: You still have one spurious `\onehalfspacing` command at end of MWE :-( . Is now your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE had errors. In its edits you remove part of them, but MWE still not working. Testing it you should receive message about these errors and should see, that compilation was stopped.

After repairing your MWE I observe, that the first table is to long that can be fit below appendix title, so it is moved to the end of long tables what probably is not desired. This you can correct with using `longtable` for the first table too or split it to two parts and put them in parallel in the `table` environment.

In my test I use the following MWE in which I consider all my comments below your question, reorganize your preamble a litle bit and add new package `makecell` for column headers  in the first table:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{report}
    \usepackage{geometry,}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{float,subfig}
    \usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
    \usepackage{adjustbox,ragged2e}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{booktabs, dcolumn, 
                makecell,                          % <--- new
                longtable, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}  % <--- new
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}                      % <--- new
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
     \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

    \begin{document}
    \listoffigures % Prints the list of figures
    \listoftables % Prints the list of tables
    \tableofcontents

    %%APPENDIX A
    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Tables}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}[t]{ c c }
            \toprule
            \thead{Geological\\ fm}  & \thead{number of\\ samples examined}\\
            \midrule
            MAC&    34\\
            OMT &34\\
            FAF &18\\
            PSM &16\\
            GRE &13\\
            ARB &8\\
            ACC &7\\
            ACCa&7\\
            GOT &7\\
            PRS &7\\
            CGV &6\\
            MAA &5\\
            CCA &4\\
            MDD &4\\
            STO &4\\
            ANL &3\\
            CLF &3\\
            MRQ &3\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{ c c }
            \toprule
            \thead{Geological\\ fm}  & \thead{number of\\ samples examined}\\
            \midrule
            RET &3\\
            ACCb &2\\
            bv &2\\
            CCVd& 2\\
            MAS &2\\
            MVE &2\\
            OST &2\\
            PRC &2\\
            SSR &2\\
            VEU &2\\
            CCVb &1\\
            CCVc &1\\
            LVG &1\\
            MACa &1\\
            MRR &1\\
            pv  &1\\
            VINa &1\\
            \vphantom{X}&   \\  % empty line
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Number of samples for each geological formation examined in the laboratory for the unit weight determination.}
        \label{tab:count_pesovol}
    \end{table}

    \begin{longtable}{S[table-format=2.0]
            *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]}
            S[table-format=2.1,detect-weight]
        }
        \caption{Results of linear regression model for the prediction of R mean (R mean predicted).}
        \label{tab:model_res_t} \\
        \toprule
        {Mv(\%)}
        & {L mean }& {R mean observed} & {R mean predicted} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{Results of linear regression model for the prediction of R mean (R mean predicted).}\\
        \toprule
        {Mv(\%)}
        & {L mean }& {R mean observed} & {R mean predicted} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        85  &   188.2   &   10.0    &   9.3 \\
        80  &   375.3   &   10.5    &   20.4    \\
        75  &   326.2   &   23.4    &   17.5    \\
        40  &   247.1   &   15.6    &   13.1    \\
        30  &   215.1   &   18.2    &   11.3    \\
        25  &   258.9   &   16.0    &   13.9    \\
        20  &   243.8   &   16.9    &   13.1    \\
        20  &   264.0   &   11.8    &   14.3    \\
        10  &   285.4   &   17.6    &   15.6    \\
        10  &   295.7   &   19.3    &   16.2    \\
        5   &   239.9   &   14.7    &   13.0    \\
        5   &   281.3   &   23.3    &   15.4    \\
        0   &   296.9   &   18.4    &   16.4    \\
        0   &   304.8   &   21.1    &   16.9    \\
        0   &   321.9   &   21.6    &   17.9    \\
        0   &   375.6   &   27.1    &   21.0    \\
        0   &   413.0   &   21.1    &   23.2    \\
        0   &   444.9   &   18.4    &   25.1    \\
        0   &   449.1   &   34.3    &   25.4    \\
        0   &   484.7   &   34.3    &   27.5    \\
        0   &   489.3   &   33.9    &   27.7    \\
        0   &   505.8   &   21.1    &   28.7    \\
        0   &   542.1   &   41.9    &   30.9    \\
        0   &   563.9   &   34.3    &   32.1    \\
        0   &   572.4   &   34.3    &   32.6    \\
        0   &   646.2   &   34.3    &   37.0    \\
        0   &   662.2   &   41.9    &   37.9    \\
        0   &   538.8   &   23.1    &   30.7    \\
        0   &   466.3   &   18.2    &   26.4    \\
        0   &   377.9   &   12.7    &   21.2    \\
        0   &   636.7   &   32.6    &   36.4    \\
        0   &   691.2   &   38.4    &   39.7    \\
        0   &   766.8   &   48.6    &   44.1    \\
        0   &   614.5   &   24.3    &   35.1    \\
        0   &   543.7   &   23.0    &   31.0    \\
        0   &   499.8   &   16.5    &   28.4    \\
        0   &   710.3   &   35.1    &   40.8    \\
        0   &   774.0   &   50.5    &   44.6    \\
        0   &   780.0   &   49.1    &   44.9    \\
        0   &   761.3   &   49.5    &   43.8    \\
        0   &   762.9   &   50.1    &   43.9    \\
        0   &   767.0   &   50.3    &   44.1    \\
        0   &   588.1   &   35.0    &   33.6    \\
        0   &   601.7   &   38.7    &   34.4    \\
        0   &   423.9   &   11.3    &   23.9    \\
        0   &   425.3   &   10.5    &   24.0    \\
        0   &   623.7   &   29.9    &   35.7    \\
    \end{longtable}
    %\onehalfspacing

    %\singlespacing
    \begin{longtable}{S[table-format=2.0]
            *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]}
            S[table-format=2.1,detect-weight]
        }
        \caption{Results of Bayesian Network model for the prediction of R mean (R mean predicted).}
        \label{tab:model_res_tot_BN} \\
        \toprule
        {Mv(\%)}
        & {L mean }& {R mean observed} & {R mean predicted} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{Results of Bayesian Network model for the prediction of R mean (R mean predicted).} \\
        \toprule
        {Mv(\%)}
        & {L mean }& {R mean observed} & {R mean predicted} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        85 &188.2   &10.0   &8.6  \\
        80 &375.3   &10.5   &20   \\
        75 &326.2   &23.4   &19.1 \\
        40 &247.1   &15.6   &14.3 \\
        30 &215.1   &18.2   &11.5 \\
        25 &258.9   &16.0   &15.2 \\
        20 &243.8   &16.9   &14.1 \\
        20 &264.0   &11.8   &15.6 \\
        10 &285.4   &17.6   &16.5 \\
        10 &295.7   &19.3   &17.1 \\
        5  &239.9   &14.7   &13.9 \\
        5  &281.3   &23.3   &16.3 \\
        0  &780.0   &49.1   &50.6 \\
        0  &264     &11.8   &15.6 \\
        0  &285.8   &17.6   &16.5 \\
        0  &295.7   &19.3   &17.1 \\
        0  &239.9   &14.7   &13.9 \\
        0  &296.9   &18.4   &17.4 \\
        0  &304.8   &21.1   &18.0 \\
        0  &321.9   &21.6   &19.1 \\
        0  &375.6   &27.1   &20.3 \\
        0  &413.0   &21.1   &21.4 \\
        0  &444.9   &18.4   &22.8 \\
        0  &449.1   &34.3   &23.3 \\
        0  &484.7   &34.3   &25.3 \\
        0  &489.3   &33.9   &25.3 \\
        0  &505.8   &21.1   &26.4 \\
        0  &542.1   &41.9   &28.3 \\
        0  &563.9   &34.3   &29.8 \\
        0  &572.4   &34.3   &30.3 \\
        0  &646.2   &34.3   &35.7 \\
        0  &662.2   &41.9   &36.9 \\
        0  &538.8   &23.1   &28.7 \\
        0  &466.3   &18.2   &24.2 \\
        0  &377.9   &12.7   &20.4 \\
        0  &636.7   &32.6   &35.2 \\
        0  &691.2   &38.4   &38.6 \\
        0  &766.8   &48.6   &43.3 \\
        0  &614.5   &24.3   &33.6 \\
        0  &543.7   &23.0   &29.0 \\
        0  &499.8   &16.5   &25.9 \\
        0  &710.3   &35.1   &38.8 \\
        0  &774.0   &50.5   &48.5 \\
        0  &780.0   &49.1   &50.6 \\
        0  &761.3   &49.5   &41.1 \\
        0  &762.9   &50.1   &41.4 \\
        0  &767.0   &50.3   &43.4 \\
        0  &588.1   &35.0   &31.4 \\
        0  &601.7   &38.7   &32.6 \\
        0  &423.9   &11.3   &21.9 \\
        0  &425.3   &10.5   &22.2 \\
        0  &623.7   &29.9   &33.7 \\
    \end{longtable}
    %\onehalfspacing
    \end{appendices}

    %\printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

Above MWE produce the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you still have problems with compiling your real document containing appendix as is in above MWE, than source of your problem is not in it but somewhere else in your document.

Comment: that's perfect @Zarko